# using Generics to Cast an Enum to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, generics

im trying to create a method i can call which will return me a Dictionary of type  `Dictionary<int,string>` from an Enum.

i want to use generics.

this is my code so far...

```
public class Enums
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary<T>()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
           .Cast<typeof(T)>()
           .ToDictionary(t => (int)t, t => t.ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fuel Type Enum
    /// </summary>
    public enum FuelTypes
    {
        Petrol = 1,
        Diesel = 2,
        Hybrid = 3,
        Electric = 4
    }
}
```

unit test...

```
[TestClass]
public class EnumTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetEnumDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict = Enums.GetEnumDictionary<Enums.FuelTypes>();
        Assert.IsTrue(dict != null);
    }
}
```

the compliation error im getting is

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'

can anyone see where my error is ?

Comment: It looks like you didn't post your actual code. The error message is about `GetEnumDictionary(Type)` method, which you didn't post.

Comment: that is at the top -> public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary<T>()

Comment: That's a different method. The error message talks about something like `public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary(Type type)`, or similar.

Comment: yes your right, im updating now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two main errors in the GetEnumDictionary method:

First, `Cast<typeof(T)>` doesn't make sense. It's simply `Cast<T>`.

Then, you can't simply cast a value of type T to and int, but you must cast it to object first.
So, you should change your method like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
       .Cast<T>()
       .ToDictionary(t => (int)(object)t, t => t.ToString());
}
```

But the problem is that you can pass whatever type you want to T, even non-enum types.
Unfortunately you cant constraint generic type to be an Enum, so you need to check it at runtime:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary<T>()
{
    if(!typeof(T).IsEnum)
       throw new ArgumentException("T is not an Enum type");
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
       .Cast<T>()
       .ToDictionary(t => (int)(object)t, t => t.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT :**

As correctly pointed out by svick, the underlying type of an enum can be different from `int`. 
So for example it won't work with enums like these:

```
enum MyEnum : long
{
   Foo,
   Bar,
}
```

To be safer, maybe you should check also that at runtime:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary<T>()
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T is not an Enum type");
    if (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != typeof(int))
        throw new ArgumentException("The underlying type of the enum T is not Int32");
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<T>()
        .ToDictionary(t => (int)(object)t, t => t.ToString());
}
```

A final note.

You could change the code to support enums with integral values that fit into an `Int32`. In fact you can simply put a `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of using a direct cast to `int` or, as correctly shown in other answers, you can exploit the `IConvertible` interface.
However, in my opinion, it doesn't give you many benefits. Since this method is not really type safe, you should use it when you know what you're doing; therefore, in case you want a dictionary out of a "long-enum" (for example), just use/make another method...

Comment: Be careful with this, it will work only for `enum`s that have underlying type of `int` (though almost all `enum`s do).

Comment: Yep, you're right forgot it. I'm going to mention it in the answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
.Cast<typeof(T)>()
```

You are trying to use an instance of the `Type` class as a generic parameter, you should use the type instead:

```
.Cast<T>()
```

Comment: Excellent, please note i also changed -> .ToDictionary(t => Convert.ToInt32(t), t => t.ToString());

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it:

```
public static IDictionary<int, string> GetEnumDictionary<T>()
where T : IConvertible
{
    return Enum
       .GetValues(typeof(T))
       .Cast<T>()
       .ToDictionary(
           t => t.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
       ,   t => t.ToString()
       );
}
```

There were several small problems in your code:

- The `Cast` should be to `T`, not `typeof(T)`
- Casting `T` to `int` is prohibited, so you need to use the fact that `enum`s are `IConvertible`

Here is a quick [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/wPUI8K).